# Has anyone already written JavaScript versions of Zend Validators?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, zend-framework, validation

I've built my Zend Forms to push validation params to the client for JS validation. I'm not excited about having to re-write many of Zend's Validators in JS however. I don't want to reinvent the wheel if it's not necessary.

Has anyone found or written a jQuery-based set of validators that reproduce the Zend Validators' functionality for client-side validation?

Comment: Why do this task? Simply use AJAX request to validate the (partial) form using your already written code in ZF.

Comment: I would advice you not to use JavaScript for validation purposes. The user can simply disable JavaScript or modify the validation script and pass it with invalid data. So serverside validation is alyways a must. If you want to validate to tell the user, that somethings wrong before he sends the form, you might use AurelioDeRosa's solution.

Comment: Ajaxifying the validation is fine for an application that may not have all that many users. However, with an application that may have millions of users, all of those ajax calls can mount to substantial overhead on the webserver. Still, all good points. I may just do that.

Comment: Client-side validation via JavaScript is NOT at all intended to replace server-side validation. It is "convenience validation" designed to help the user to not submit bad data that will be rejected by the server in the first place, and thus avoid user frustration.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @AurelioDeRosa in the comment you can use an ajax-call of your current form to validate the fields. The video-cast goes into field-by-field validation, however you can easily adjust the code to validate on submit only or on-whatever you need.

Listen to it, it has great advice - read comments, too http://www.zendcasts.com/ajaxify-your-zend_form-validation-with-jquery/2010/04/